# How do promo codes work for newer version of app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, promotion-code

My current version is "Pending Developer Release". Promo codes will expire October 10th, the ones I've used. So the users who i've given the promo codes to gave me good feedback for app. I want to take down the current app from iTunes connect and upload a new build and get that build approved with App review. So if I get that same app approved would I get 100 new promo codes or would I still continue with the 39 codes I currently have left?

Also, do the current codes that people have now, automatically expire for the users who used it if I upload the new build and request promo codes and I'd have to give them new codes OR do the codes automatically update the app by itself if I updated the app and it's passed app review?

Comment: Codes are only good for one month and only good for the specific version they were downloaded from.

Comment: To clarify, you get 100 new promo codes with the new version.  If people have redeemed the promo code for the previous version then they get the upgrade just like any other app that they have downloaded. No need for a new code.  If they haven't  redeemed the code then their code will become invalid once you update the app and you will need to give them a new code

Comment: Is this how it currently works in 2020?  If I have a 1.0 of an app, and generate promo codes and then come out with 1.0.1, does that Invalidate any unused codes for 1.0